# useRoute() in react navigation always gets stack routes

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have the useRoute() function from `@react-navigation/native` but it seems to be getting the StackNavigator routes when I am in the tab navigation.

```
const selectedRouteName = useRoute();
useEffect(() => {
   (async () => {
       setRole(await AsyncStorage.getItem("role"));
   })();
   console.log(selectedRouteName)
   // Output: {"key": "Main-avC8enKNNKW2cPdSppXTh", "name": "Main", "params": undefined}
}, [selectedRouteName]);
```

```
const TabNav = () => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState("student");
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      setRole(await AsyncStorage.getItem("role"));
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}
      initialRouteName='Home'
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Apousies" component={Apousies} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Programma" component={Programmatismos} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Vathmoi" component={Vathmoi} />
      <Tab.Screen name="More Options" component={Vathmoi} />
      {role == "teacher" && <Tab.Screen name="SwapPeriods" component={SwapScreen} />}
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const TabNavigationComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={TabNav} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ApousiesTeachers" component={ApousiesTeachers} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Not sure what to try because I've never ran into this issue. If anyone has a link with a solution that I can't find please don't hesitate to let me know

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @devpolo - Add a dot below the icon. But I am trying to get the currently selected route and I can't do that because it gets the stack screen route